# image moves on a gameBoard

Tags: java, swing

I have this board as a gameBoard : http://puu.sh/k5e6O/c5eebd31f3.png
the idea is having an image which walks all through the board and then it ends up in one of the circles on the side ( the light colors )
I kind of ran out of ideas, any idea how to set that ?

Note:
- I'm using Swing library, and the code bellow is how i set the board into the Jframe ( Jframe = bp )

```
 gameBoard = new ImageIcon("gameBoard.png");
 JLabel gameBoard_1 = new JLabel(gameBoard);
 bp.add(gameBoard_1);
```

Comment: Perhaps you may be assuming that there is only one Java GUI library, and that given your images and descriptions, we'll know how to help you, but this is not true. There are several GUI libraries including Swing, AWT, SWT, and in order to help you, we'll need to know which library you're using and also we'll need to see pertinent code.

Comment: Sorry i did not ignore ur comment, i just forgot to answer, I guess am using SWT, as im plugging JFrames and JPanels into my code

Comment: Thank you for that information, but it seems that you're not using SWT but rather Swing (your code will likely have `import javax.swing.` within it). Let me update your question's tags, and you'll still want to post pertinent code, preferably an [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you need a few things.

First, each image needs a "center" (image coordinates) and each valid location on the board needs a coordinate (board coordinates).

Then you need to use some math to translate the image to the correct coordinate.  It is as simple as

```
placedImage = imageCoords + boardCoords
```

And since the image has a boundary, it makes sense to set the image boundary is based on the image coordinates.  This means that the translated boundary is the same as

```
upperLeftBoundary = boundaryInImageCoords + boardCoords
```

Then your drawing routines should draw the board, and draw the images, but in your case, you want to draw them both in board coordinates.

If you know linear algebra, you can store the "translation" between coordinate systems in a matrix, and relocating the image could be as simple as

```
boardCoordinates = locationTranslation * imageCoordinates
```

Where imageCoordinates is stored as a vector, and locationTranslation is a matrix of the form

```
T = [1 0 dx]
    [0 1 dy]
    [0 0 1 ]
```

Comment: thanks very much, is there a code wise example that i may be able to follow ?

Comment: @Neyon: you still have ignored my comment to your original question. How can anyone recommend code if we still have no idea what GUI library  or what code you're using? Please fix this. 1+ to this decent answer btw.

Comment: @Neyon Programming is writing, not copying.  While we do stand on the work of others, you can't just paste together a book from copied pages of other books and have anything that makes sense.  For the drawing, I suggest Swing http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ and for the multiplying of matrices, I suggest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication.

Comment: @EdwiBuck, yeah was asking for something like this, documentation which will explain more :) thanks a lot

Comment: @Neyon Glad to have helped, have a great day.  Post some of your stuff if you run into problems.

Comment: @EdwinBuck when you say : each image needs a "center" (image coordinates) and each valid location on the board needs a coordinate (board coordinates). what do u mean ? sorry am new to this stuff trying to learn and its still a bit vague to me and looks like impossible job!

Comment: So, If I were doing it.  I'd have the image be located at it's center (so it is easy to know where it is on the board).  That means it might be contained in the rectangle described by the following four points (10, 10), (10, -10), (-10, -10), (-10, 10).  and have a size of 21 pixels by 21 pixels.  Then when I translate it to the correct location, by multiplying each coordinate against the transform matrix, I might get a set of coordinates like (120, 80), (120, 59), (99, 59), (99, 80) or something like that...

Comment: There are other ways to do it, but they don't naturally center themselves.  For example, tracking the upper left as the "origin" means that to center anything, you need to calculate it's center and position based on that.  By putting everything centered at the origin, the math is cleaner.